# stop large size mails notification from a RubyGem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rubygems, actionmailer

I'm working on a Rubygem , basically the gem sends email notification but sometimes the email size is too large and when the client receives it their app crashes.

Note:the gem uses ActionMailer to send mails

So I want to implement a method to stop the gem from sending a mail if its size passes a certain limit and instead send this notification to the client "Content is too large to be displayed".

I am still a Ruby on Rails newbie,I want to create a method that first checks the size of the mail before it's send then passes a if condition to see if it can be send or not but I don't know where to start actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your mail size is increasing because you are rendering some content in a loop within your `ActionMailer` views.

So, an easy way to add that limit is by checking how many elements do you have in your collection. If it exceeds some number say "Content is too large" else render everything.

```
<% if @my_model.some_collection.size > 10 %>
  <p>Content is too large to be displayed.</p>
<% else %>
  <%= @my_model.some_collection.each do |elem| %>
    # ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Alternatively

You can do it using 2 other methods:

1. [ActionMailer callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks)
2. [ActionMailer interceptors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-emails)